# Putting incomplete nested lists in a rectangular ndarray

Tags: python, list, numpy, nested-lists, multidimensional-array

In Python (also using numpy) I have a list of lists of lists, with each list being different lengths.

```
[
    [
         ["header1","header2"],
         ["---"],
         [],
         ["item1","value1"]
    ],

    [
         ["header1","header2","header3"],
         ["item2","value2"],
         ["item3","value3","value4","value5"]
    ]
]
```

I want to make this data structure rectangular: i.e. guarantee that `len(list[x])` is constant for all `x`, `len(list[x][y])` is constant for all x,y, etc.

(This is because I want to import the data structure into numpy)

I can think of various unpythonic ways of doing such a thing (iterate over structure, record maximum length at each level, have second pass and pad values with `None`, but there must be a better way.

(I also would like the solution to not be dependant on the dimensionality of the structure; i.e. it should work on lists of such structures, too...)

Is there a simple way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: You have three levels of lists here - what levels does it need to be rectangular on? (Or cubic, I guess, for all three).

Comment: What are you going to do with the data once it's in NumPy?

Comment: Lattyware: All of them; the data structure I want in the end should be describable as an x-by-y-by-z cuboid.

KarlKnechtel: Using Numpy's multidimensional slicing, identify the data I'm actually interested in based on things like "in the same column as the string "My Data" in the same row as the string "Header Row"".

Comment: How did you get to having this data in the first place? Is it coming out of some of your other code, or is it being read from csv/json/xml or some other form of structured data?

Comment: A variety of sources, all being handled by different python modules, all of which output nested lists. The code I'm writing is the first moment that the different sources have a common codebase.

Comment: As a slight meta-point, I'm really curious why you want to use Numpy for this. What does Numpy offer in this situation that normal lists don't? More broadly, although numpy is perfectly capable of storing all manner of weird data types, I'm not sure why anyone uses it for non-simple types (this is genuine curiosity!).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `ndarray` with the desired dimensions and readily read your list. Since your list is incomplete you must catch the `IndexError`, which can be done in a `try / exception` block.

Using `numpy.ndenumerate` allows the solution to be easily extensible to more dimensions (adding more indexes `i,j,k,l,m,n,...` in the for loop below):

```
import numpy as np
test = [ [ ["header1","header2"],
           ["---"],
           [],
           ["item1","value1"] ],
         [ ["header1","header2","header3"],
           ["item2","value2"],
           ["item3","value3","value4","value5"] ] ]


collector = np.empty((2,4,4),dtype='|S20')

for (i,j,k), v in np.ndenumerate( collector ):
    try:
        collector[i,j,k] = test[i][j][k]
    except IndexError:
        collector[i,j,k] = ''


print collector
#array([[['header1', 'header2', '', ''],
#        ['---', '', '', ''],
#        ['', '', '', ''],
#        ['item1', 'value1', '', '']],
#       [['header1', 'header2', 'header3', ''],
#        ['item2', 'value2', '', ''],
#        ['item3', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'],
#        ['', '', '', '']]],  dtype='|S10')
```