# How to get every element in a list of list of lists?

Tags: python

I'm making a heart game for my assignment but I don't know how to get every element in a list of list:

```
>>>Cards = [[["QS","5H","AS"],["2H","8H"],["7C"]],[["9H","5C],["JH"]],[["7D"]]]
```

and what comes to my mind is :

```
for values in cards:
    for value in values:
```

But I think I just got element that has 2 list. How to calculate the one that has 3 and 1 list in the cards?

Comment: I edited your code to add in an additional `"` as it is missing. Why did you revert that edit?

Comment: You will need some recursivity to achieve what you want in a clean way.

Comment: Do you have all cards at the same depth? Then you just need to go there.

Comment: It looks like you have a list of list of lists, but haven't closed the final bracket.

Comment: @Erika Sawajiri Isn't it an error in the last item ['7D']? Shouldn't it be [['7D']]?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like this:

```
>>> Cards = [[["QS","5H","AS"],["2H","8H"],["7C"]],[["9H","5C"],["JH"]],["7D"]]
>>> from compiler.ast import flatten
>>> flatten(Cards) 
['QS', '5H', 'AS', '2H', '8H', '7C', '9H', '5C', 'JH', '7D']
```

As, nacholibre pointed out, the `compiler` package is deprecated. This is the source of `flatten`:

```
def flatten(seq):
    l = []
    for elt in seq:
        t = type(elt)
        if t is tuple or t is list:
            for elt2 in flatten(elt):
                l.append(elt2)
        else:
            l.append(elt)
    return l
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't know this existed.

Comment: I don't think they intended that function to be used like this, but if it works ... :).

Comment: Important: `Deprecated since version 2.6: The compiler package has been removed in Python 3.`

Comment: @Hans but your flatten function will separate all the elements like 7 and C. What I want is 7C

Comment: Will it? I think it will only iterate lists and tuples, not strings.

Comment: The type check in the quoted code is pretty ugly and fragile (it won't handle list or tuple subclasses). A better one would be `if isinstance(elt, (list, tuple))`. If you're making your own flatten code anyway, you might want to make it a generator too, rather than building a (possibly unneeded) list.

Comment: I just copied the code from compiler.ast.flatten. Of course a generator would be nice too, but that depends on the actual requirements.

Answer (score 6):

Slightly obscure oneliner:

```
>>> [a for c in Cards for b in c for a in b]
['QS', '5H', 'AS', '2H', '8H', '7C', '9H', '5C', 'JH', '7', 'D']
```

You might want to give a, b and c more descriptive names.

Comment: it seems correct for the begginning part. But the 7 and d is separated

Comment: @blubber the problem is they aren't nested uni-formally (which is an odd way to store your game data...)

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Well you can't use this then, it only works on regularly formed lists.

Comment: @ErikaSawajiri the last item in the list should be [['7D']], isn't it a typo?

Answer (score 4):

If your cards are nested in a unwieldy way:

```
>>> Cards = [[["QS","5H","AS"],["2H","8H"],["7C"]],[["9H","5C"],["JH"]],["7D"]]
>>> def getCards(cardList,myCards=[]): #change this to myCards, and pass in a list to mutate this is just for demo
        if isinstance(cardList,list):
            for subList in cardList:
                getCards(subList)
        else:
            myCards.append(cardList)
        return myCards
>>> getCards(Cards)
['QS', '5H', 'AS', '2H', '8H', '7C', '9H', '5C', 'JH', '7D']
```

Will recursivly go through the list and find all the elements. These are some timeings I've run comparing performance of the selected `flattern` method to mine:

```
>>> print(timeit.timeit(r'getCards([[["QS","5H","AS"],["2H","8H"],["7C"]],[["9H","5C"],["JH"]],["7D"]],[])',setup="from clas import getCards"))
5.24880099297
>>> timeit.timeit(r'flatten([[["QS","5H","AS"],["2H","8H"],["7C"]],[["9H","5C"],["JH"]],["7D"]])',setup="from compiler.ast import flatten")
7.010887145996094
```

Answer (score 2):

Your list is an incomplete nested list, so you can first make it rectangular, [using the procedure explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16697665/832621), for example, and then flatten the resulting `numpy.ndarray`.

The "ifs" below wouldn't be necessary as well if the last element ['7D'] was [['7D']] (then the other answers would also work).

```
import numpy as np
collector = np.zeros((3,3,3),dtype='|S20')

for (i,j,k), v in np.ndenumerate( collector ):
    try:
        if not isinstance(cards[i], str):
            if not isinstance(cards[i][j], str):
                collector[i,j,k] = cards[i][j][k]
            else:
                collector[i,j,0] = cards[i][j]
        else:
            collector[i,0,0] = cards[i]
    except IndexError:
        collector[i,j,k] = ''

print collector[collector<>''].flatten()
```

Answer (score 2):

Using generators, it's possible to write a much more readable implementation of `flatten`:

```
def flatten(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        for e1 in l:
            for e2 in flatten(e1):
                yield e2
    else:
        yield l
```

Or, if you're using Python 3.3, which added the [`yield from`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) syntax:

```
def flatten(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        for e in l:
            yield from flatten(e)
    else:
        yield l
```

Result:

```
>>> list(flatten([[["QS","5H","AS"],["2H","8H"],["7C"]],[["9H","5C"],["JH"]],[["7D"]]]))
['QS', '5H', 'AS', '2H', '8H', '7C', '9H', '5C', 'JH', '7D']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use 2 nested [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten the list:

```
In [32]: Cards
Out[32]: [[['QS', '5H', 'AS'], ['2H', '8H'], ['7C']], [['9H', '5C'], ['JH']], ['7D']]

In [33]: from itertools import chain

In [34]: [k for k in chain.from_iterable([i for i in chain.from_iterable(Cards)])]
Out[34]: ['QS', '5H', 'AS', '2H', '8H', '7C', '9H', '5C', 'JH', '7', 'D']
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution is very robust for any kind of nested lists or tuples (to add other iterable types just add more `or isinstance(...)` in the code below.

It just calls recursively a function that unfolds itself:

```
def unfold(lst):
    output = []
    def _unfold(i):
        if isinstance(i, list) or isinstance(i, tuple):
            [_unfold(j) for j in i]
        else:
            output.append(i)
    _unfold(lst)
    return output

print unfold(cards)
#['QS', '5H', 'AS', '2H', '8H', '7C', '9H', '5C', 'JH', '7D']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Flatten a list](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list#Python) from Rosetta Code you could do:

```
>>> def flatten(lst):
    return sum( ([x] if not isinstance(x, list) else flatten(x)
             for x in lst), [] )

>>> Cards = [[["QS","5H","AS"],["2H","8H"],["7C"]],[["9H","5C"],["JH"]],["7D"]]
>>> flatten(Cards)
['QS', '5H', 'AS', '2H', '8H', '7C', '9H', '5C', 'JH', '7D']
>>>
```

The solution only flattens nested lists  - not tuples or strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain, imap

l= [[["QS","5H","AS"],["2H","8H"],["7C"]],[["9H","5C"],["JH"]],[["7D"]]]

k = list(chain.from_iterable(imap(list, l)))
m = list(chain.from_iterable(imap(list, k)))

print m
```

output: ['QS', '5H', 'AS', '2H', '8H', '7C', '9H', '5C', 'JH', '7D']

Itertools is amazing!